# Voltage divider with 2 Input

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-divider

Can you help me solve the below circuit with formula, I have 2 voltage source for a voltage divider and what is the output voltage and can u elaborate with formula

[image: input]

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? Do you know Ohm's law?

Comment: If you are asked to find the voltage at a node, apply KCL. That will be the easiest approach. You may study this book " Fundamentals of Electric Circuits - by Charles K. Alexander and Matthew N.O. Sadiku". This book is relatively easy to understand.

Comment: If you don't know about Kirchoff's law then there's a lot of content on youtube.

Comment: Ok thankful for the answers

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm2zUz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The voltage at V<sub>O</sub> will be proportional to the resistance ratio and a function of the two voltage sources.*

Can you work it out now?

Answer (score 1):

You can impress your teacher, if you enlarge your homework question with the case when V1 = -20 V or V3 = -0.5 V. You can see more than 4 million web pages dedicated to this case if you type *op-amp inverting amplifier* in the Google window.

[image: Static virtual ground]

If I have piqued your interest to this humble 2-resistor circuit, you can play with it by replacing the two resistors with a potentiometer like they did in this [wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film):

[image: Resistor summer]

Comment: Please don't give away solutions to homework questions. We generally try to give hints and help lead the OP to finding their own solution.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, I think there is still enough OP left to do. Besides, I have given additional reading guidelines. Maybe, here is the place to share some teaching experience. When I discuss these basic electrical circuits, I show (briefly) their main applications in electronic circuits. In this way, students understand their meaning. Later, when I enter electronic circuits, I show (remind) them the simple passive circuit inside them. This makes teaching in technical schools more than engineering. That means having the inner need (vocation) to do it. I am looking to meet such teachers...

Answer (score 0):

Use the superposition principle

Comment: You're making this much too easy! This is clearly a homework question.

Comment: ... and possibly an open book exam question in Covid-19 circumstances. Give leading tips rather than solutions.

Comment: my bad, edited...